# Largest Palindrome 3 digits C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, palindrome

I cannot figure out why this code isn't working. It doesn't even seem to be going through my for loops and nested loops. I'm very new to programing. I have been trying to answer Euler questions for practice. Sorry if my code is awful.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        string str = to_string(x);

        for(string::reverse_iterator rit=str.rbegin(); rit!=str.rend(); ++rit) {
            string pal = to_string(*rit);
            if(pal == str) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int max[] = {0, 0};


        for(int i=999; i>99; i--) {
            for( int j =999; j>99; j--) {
            int pal = i*j;
                if(isPalindrome(pal) == true) {
                max[1] = pal;
                if(max[1] > max[0]){
                    max[0] = pal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << max[0];
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to return true in isPalindrome after comparing complete string. ir return true should be outside for loop

Comment: I see your point. I put the if loop outside but it still didn't change the results. It always prints zero.

Comment: The problem is in the `isPalindrome` function. You are incorrectly constructing the reversed string. It may be easier conceptually if you create a function specifically for reversing the string (let's call it `reverseString`). Then you can replace the loop in `isPalindrome` with `string pal = reverseString(str);`. After that, you just check if they are equal and return the result.

Comment: Alber I think that is a really good idea. I'm a little confused how it isn't reversing it correctly. Like I said I'm very new, so just reversing a string is a learning experience.

Comment: @Curtis2point0 Being confused right now is no problem. The good thing about making a separate function for your string reversing is that you can test it separately to see what it is really doing. You could, for instance, call `reverseString` with a few test strings and print out the results. That should help diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to return true in `isPalindrome` after comparing complete string. ie `return true;` should be outside `for` loop

And for checking largest 3 digit palindrome why are you passing `int pal = i*j;` ie for first iteration `999*999`. Check this

```
bool isPalindrome(int x) {
string str = to_string(x);
string pal = str;
std::reverse(pal.begin(),pal.end()); 

  if(pal == str) {
      return true;
  }else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I see where the title can be unclear. I'm looking for a palindrome that is the product of two 3-digit numbers.